# What is the "apparatus fontium"?

Tags: medieval-latin, philosophy-terms

I have encountered with **apparatus fontium** for example in this reference:

> Gundissalinus, *De divisione philosophiae*, **apparatus fontium** ad pp. 36 –7

What is it and what is it's the literal meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Apparātus* is a very general-purpose word in Latin, but in classics and textual criticism, it refers to extra material that an editor has attached to a work; I'd translate it as "footnote". For example, an *apparātus criticus* explains how the primary sources differ for a given line.

An *apparātus fontium*, then, is a "footnote of sources". In other words, an editor has added a list of the sources that the original author refers to. If the author quotes Vergil, for instance, the *apparātus fontium* for that line will provide the book and line numbers.

Comment: Your answer is quite elucidating. According to the literal meaning of **apparatus** and regarding your answer, **providing of sources** may be a more accurate translation

Comment: @AliNikzad That would work too! I just try to use a noun for it, because in other phrases like _apparātus criticus_, "critical providing" sounds weird. "Provision", maybe, if people still used that word in its original sense?

Comment: Yes, "provision" is much better.